# Duvida sobre relacionamento entre tabelas Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ola, sou iniciante em Rails, (montando meu primeiro sistema) e tenho duas duvidas sobre relacionamento entre tabelas:

1.) Tenho um modelo **Linha** com os atributos **origem** e **destino** que devem fazer referência a um outro modelo **Local**, ou seja Linha tem um atributo origem que é um local e outro atributo destino que é outro local, como faço essa associação?

2.) Linha representa um trajeto entre um local e outro. Além dos dos pontos de origem e destino a linha passa em vários **pontos de referência** quando está indo (origem > destino) e outros tantos quando esta voltando (destino > origem). Cada ponto de referência deste é um local "referenciado", que além dos atributos herdados de Local deve ter uma informação de "distancia", ou seja, Linha, Sentido Ida, após 20 minutos passa no Local x.

Olhando o relacionamento entre os objetos (se facilitar o entendimento teria algo assim):

- Local {descrição:string}
- Referencia Extends Local { distancia:integer }
- Linha {origem:Local, destino:Local, referenciasIda:[Referencia], referenciasVolta:[Referencias]}

Mais como criar os modelos para representar isso??**texto em negrito**

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tem uma entidade Linha que tem várias entidades Local, e se um Local pertencer somente a uma Linha você terá uma Linha que pertence a um Local.

Segundo a mesma entidade Linha tem várias entidades Referência

```
class Linha
  has_many :locais
  has_many :referencia 
end

class Local
  belongs_to :linha
end

class Referencia
  belongs_to :linha
end
```

As referências pode ter atributos que indique a posição junto aos locais, sendo assim você pode calcular o valor da distância entre as referências e/ou locais.

Qualquer dúvida sobre relacionamentos os guides é uma excelente referência: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association